# Laravel say I'm on production when I'm not

Tags: php, heroku, laravel

Works fine on my local. But when Heroku tries to build the app with the following command, it aborts it and says I'm on production, even though I use the `--force` flag:

```
 php artisan migrate:refresh --seed --force
```

And I'm clearly not on production, because if I was it wouldn't be able to connect to the database at all. The production database settings are different. And it migrates and seeds just fine if I do it through the bash console.

Comment: Your environment detection settings are wrong then.

Comment: Configure your environment file. Check the local/host name, of your machine. Try "hostname" on terminal.

Comment: How can my environment detection settings be wrong, when after I confirm running the command, it uses the `dev` database settings when migrating and seeding? If it didn't it would choke because the production settings are totally different.

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function(){
if(isset($_SERVER['APP_ENVIRONMENT'])) {
    return $_SERVER['APP_ENVIRONMENT'];
}
return 'local';
```

});

Where APP_ENVIRONMENT is set in the apache virtual host config, (like this):

```
SetEnv APP_ENVIRONMENT local
```

(On development, staging and production servers the value for APP_ENVIRONMENT and the default return value would obviously be different). That lets artisan pick up the environment, even though $_SERVER isn't available to artisan commands.

Comment: That's kinda how I do it to. But that's besides the point as the problem is not that it uses the wrong settings. The problem is that it claims I am using the production settings.